# Importing Agisoft Models Into Blender

Tags: import, photogrammetry

I'm learning Blender and thought I would try importing some of the models I've created in Agisoft into Blender, however I'm running into an issue, nothing shows up.
I'm exporting the models from Agisoft as an OBJ with a matching texture file, I've tried both real world coords and local. It is loading as I can see it in the scene collection but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong to make it visible or what I need to do further, any ideas?. Is there a better method to data from Agisoft? Below is a screenshot, thanks in advance!

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Result After Shift C]

Comment: It's likely to be a scale issue.  Type "A" to select everything. If you have a number bad, hit the period key on the number pad. If not type SHIFT-C on the keyboard.  Does your object show up?

Comment: Thanks for the response! When I type in Shift-C the view zooms into what for the lack of a better term is an orange lollipop, I'm too new to blender to know what it is, but it's not the model. It seems I can't add photos here, I'll try to add another screenshot to the original post.

Comment: If the object is too small and the camera/viewport is too close to the object, viewport/camera clipping might be occuring. Check out the View tab or Camera properties and trying reducing the min clipping distance.

Comment: Thanks for the help Bruno, I tried adjusting the clipping distances, no luck. The model is over 8 Ha., and 500,000Mb in size, could file size be an issue? I thought originally it might be projection but WGS84, local coords and UTM all behave the same. I'm doing something wrong but not sure what!

Comment: The problem appears to be associated with the texture file, if I select the OBJ by itself and then select Frame Selected I zoom right to it, doing the same thing with the texture file sends me elsewhere. I'll have to see how I'm exporting the texture file to see what is wrong with it.